# Hide .svn directories with Proftpd

Tags: ftp, svn, proftpd

Is it possible to hide directories with Proftpd?

Specifically .svn directories.

There is a [HideFiles](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_HideFiles.html) but not a **HideDirectories** directive.
The problem with HideFiles is that it doesn't match on full path.

```
<Directory /home/ftp_user/my_project >

    # Despite trying to hide this directory it still shows up 
    # as /.svn in the ftp client.

    HideFiles "^\.svn" 

    <Limit ALL>
        allowuser ftp_user
    </Limit>
</Directory>
```

Is there another way to hide directories?

Comment: +1 - those `.svn` folders constantly cause issues when someone downloads a site via FTP that was one a subversion working copy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the HideFiles [documentation](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_HideFiles.html), HideFiles only gives files "hidden-ness", it doesn't actually hide them. To hide them, you need to use IgnoreHidden within a Limit block. So, try this:

```
<Directory /home/ftp_user/my_project>

    HideFiles ^\.svn$

    <Limit ALL>
        AllowUser ftp_user
        IgnoreHidden on
    </Limit>
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Directory must be use /

```
<Directory />
# Enable hiding data based on user, group, and files the logged
# in user would have no access to.
    HideNoAccess on
    HideUser on
    HideGroup on
# Hide files in the parent directories.
    HideFiles (^\..*)
    <Limit ALL>
        IgnoreHidden on
    </Limit>
</Directory>
```